# Vote locked? But I haven't voted on the answer...

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

I was trying to vote on Jin's answer to [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/are-we-happy-with-gaming-se-s-current-logo), but for some reason Stack Exchange thinks I've already voted on it.

I don't *particularly* care if my vote doesn't get counted in this instance, but I still think this is some bug.
[image]

Neither up *nor* down votes work -- both give the same message.

Comment: Are you sure you were logged in at the moment you tried it? Because Meta's login is well... messy at times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The relevant MSO request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted) is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Well that's interesting...

Comment: Ugh.  Not a good system.

Comment: This is fixed apparently.

Comment: @Resorath The question I linked to was last active 9 months ago... was there any development outside that question?

Comment: I seem to recall this having been fixed a while ago...

Comment: The comments to the accepted answer suggest it was changed in April of 2011 so that you could always vote if no arrow was lit up.

Comment: @badp http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86658

Comment: @badp no just drive by commenting while ignoring datestamps. Nevermind!